# ¿Cómo funciona el operador %?

Tags: java, lenguaje-agnóstico, operador

Alguno me puede explicar cómo funciona el operador `%`: ¿Qué es?¿Cuál es la lógica detrás de ese operador?¿Qué es lo que hace y qué es lo que devuelve?

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código en Java (aunque valdría en otros lenguajes de notación parecida):

```
char calculaLetra(int dni) 
{ 
    String juegoCaracteres="TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE"; 
    int modulo= dni % 23; 
    char letra = juegoCaracteres.charAt(modulo); 
    return letra; 
}
```

[Pregunta surgida en el [chat de SOes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33280239).]

Comment: Comunmente conocido como módulo o resto.

Comment: Yo mas que el "Que devuelve" me interesa mas el "como", el orden de las operaciones. Gran trabajo desde el chat!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

El operador `%` se le llama el operador de módulo.

Una buena definición sencilla se puede encontrar en la [documentación para este operador en C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

> El operador de % calcula el resto después de dividir el primer operando por el segundo.

Por ejemplo, digamos que estás calculando la división siguiente:

> 10 ÷ 3

Obviamente, el resultado es `3.333333....` o en otras palabras, `3` con un restante de `1`. Ese restante es el resultado de usar el operador de módulo:

> 10 % 3 = 1

Aunque no sé exactamente como los diferentes lenguajes ejecutan este operador internamente, una manera equivalente de expresarlo en estos lenguajes es:

```
// Asumiendo que "n1" y "n2" son enteros (int), esta sentencia
int restante = n1 % n2;

// equivale a...
int restante = n1 - (n1 / n2 * n2);
```

**¿Cuándo es útil usar este operador?**

Este operador tiene muchos usos.

Puede ser útil cuando tienes un número entero cualquiera y necesitas transformarlo en un entero dentro de un intervalo mas pequeño. Los hash tables usan esta técnica internamente. Por ejemplo, partiendo de un entero positivo `n`, necesitas que te devuelva un entero entre `1` y `5`. Esto se puede lograr así:

```
int resultado = (n % 5) + 1;
```

Otro ejemplo típico es cuando deseas averiguar si un número entero es par o impar:

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println("par!");
} else {
    System.out.println("impar!");
}
```

Comment: Sería `dividendo - Math.floor(dividendo/divisor) * divisor`

Comment: @Jose: Especifiqué que `n1` y `n2` son `int`s, de modo que la division resulta en un entero.

Comment: Cierto! Disculpa las molestias.

Comment: @Jose: Ninguna molestia. Aprecio todos los comentarios constructivos como los tuyos. :)

Comment: Tambien se utiliza en el algoritmo para convertir numeros en su representacion como String (String format), algo que hacemos todo el tiempo y en que lo usamos sin saberlo.

Answer (score 3):

Como bien te han comentado en las demás respuestas, devuelve el resto de una división.

Quería comentarte que un uso muy común para este operador es la división de arrays en grupos iguales utilizando bucles for. Un caso es el ya comentado en otras respuestas de pares/impares, es decir, en grupos de dos. Pero esto se puede extender a grupos de 3, 4... Por ejemplo, tenemos que confeccionar una baraja de 40 cartas e inicializar todos sus valores. En un bucle de 0 a 39, la división i / 4 nos dará una serie como esta: 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3... hasta el 9. Y el módulo i % 4 nos dará una serie como esta: 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3... Estos valores nos permiten crear cartas(valor, palo):

```
(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0,3) -> donde 0 equivale a Oros, 1 a Copas...
(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1,3)
...
(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9,3)
```

Aquí tienes el ejemplo del código en C#:

```
    public class Baraja
    {
        public Carta[] NuevaBaraja()
        {
            Carta[] baraja = new Carta[40];
            for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            {
                Carta carta = new Carta();
                carta.Valor = i / 4;
                carta.Palo = (Palos)(i % 4);
                baraja[i] = carta;
            }
            return baraja;
        }
    }

    public class Carta
    {
        public int Valor { get; set; }
        public Palos Palo { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Palos
    {
        Oros,
        Copas,
        Espadas,
        Bastos
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

El operador % te devuelve el resto de la división entre el dividendo (lo que esta a la izquierda del operador) y el divisor (el de la derecha).

La diferencia con el operador / que te devuelve el cociente

En tu ejemplo divide el numero del dni por 23 y te da el resto, lo que queda hasta la próxima división exacta por 23 (ejemplo 24 % 23 = 1).

Con ese número recoge la letra que corresponde en el `array` de `juegoCaracteres` que tienes.

Answer (score 2):

El operador `%` es un operador aritmético y representa una división entre números enteros.

Por ejemplo si tu divides `10/3` esto normalmente es = 3.33333334, con la ayuda de `%` en programación obtendrás un 1 como respuesta a esa división, ¿Por que?

```
10 : 3 = 3
-9 (3 x 3) y 10-9 = 1.
1.
```

Tu restante 1 a diferencia de el resultado de una división normal. Lo que devuelve este operador es el restante de esta división!. Hay casos en que nos gustaría saber por ejemplo Los números pares, no nos interesa saber cuantas veces puede dividir un numero a otro si no más bien ese resultado exacto.

```
 10 : 2 = 5
-10 (5 x 2 = 10)
  0
```

Nuestro restante es `0` por lo tanto si es un numero par ya que no hay un resto el cual no podemos manejar.

En tu caso particular necesitas saber el restante de una división para obtener el char dentro de tu string.

Answer (score 0):

con el operador `/` divides: por ejemplo `6/4=1`
a diferencia del operador `%` obtienes el residuo de la división por ejemplo `6%4=2`

Answer (score 0):

> Soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no tengo reputación suficiente para responderle a @sstan. Pero lo que el dice sobre que el módulo es equivalente a:

```
int restante = n1 % n2;
// equivale a...
int restante = n1 - (n1 / n2 * n2);
```

No puede ser completamente correcto a lápiz y papel. Fíjate bien en la operación matemática, te da 0 como respuesta.

Más fácil si lo ves como fraccionarios. Siendo `n1` el dividendo, `(n1/n2)` el cociente y `n2` el divisor.

```
n1-((n1/n2)*n2) = n1 - (n1/n2) × (n2/1) = n1 - ((n1*n2)/n2)
```

Cancelas a `n2` y te queda

```
n1 - n1 = 0
```

[Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KOUGWo3ACAH-Y1cVU3FC-uJIAfZbATss/view?usp=drivesdk)

Por lo tanto NO es equivalente con el tipo de dato flotante o a lápiz y papel. La función de módulo se da cuando en el cociente se encuentra un número entero, en el caso del lenguaje, cuando es formateado a un tipo de dato entero como lo hace sstan, es decir, en ese punto de la división, lo restante es retornado. 
Si se incluyen todos los decimales finitos o infinitos del cociente, el módulo siempre será igual a 0.

Pero es correcto. Comprendo a sstan y shadow. Mi resultado del módulo sería redondeando el cociente a un valor entero. Un ejemplo igual o similar a sstan que funciona sería:

```
public static void main(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Soutln("Obtenga módulo con n1: ");
    int n1 = input.nextIn();
    Soutln("Obtenga módulo con n2: ");
    int n2 = input.nextIn();

    int cociente = n1/n2;
    double modulo = n1 - (cociente*n2);

    Soutln("El módulo es: " + modulo);
}
```

Comment: pues yo he probado la equilavencia que muestra sstan y me da exactamente el mismo resultado que el operador del módulo, así que si es correcto

Comment: y si devuelve el módulo, ya que el módulo es lo que sobra de la división; por eso te comento pruebalo a lápiz y a código y lo que el puso como respuesta es totalmente válido

Comment: si hago este código en Java por ejemplo: `int nume1 = 20;
        int nume2 = 5;
        
        System.out.println(nume1 % nume2);
        
        System.out.println(nume1 - (nume1 / nume2 * nume2));` me da cero como resultado y eso es correcto

Comment: si hago este código en Java por ejemplo: `int nume1 = 20;
        int nume2 = 3;
        
        System.out.println(nume1 % nume2);
        
        System.out.println(nume1 - (nume1 / nume2 * nume2));` me da **2** como resultado y también es correcto

Comment: entonces al final tu respuesta es si o no?, por la mitad de tu pub dices que NO y el final dices que si

Comment: Así es amigo. Tienes razón, es que en ese sentido, sstan usó tipo int en las variables y no me fijé. Estaba probando con otros tipos de datos

Comment: Pero si intentas utilizar las decimas o realizar la operación matemáticamente, da 0. A lapiz y papel no puedes cambiar el tipo de dato. Son matemáticas.

Comment: solo en uno de los casos que te puse da 0 en el otro no; nadie intenta cambiar nada; lo que deberías saber es que la salida se puede formatear para indicar si deseas o no decimales @Luis Miguel

Comment: Me refiero a esto 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KOUGWo3ACAH-Y1cVU3FC-uJIAfZbATss/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: te invito a que si tienes dudas respecto a este operador y la respuesta de sstan y mis comentarios no te sattisfacen entonces lee [ask] y abre una nueva pregunta, y ahi pega el código; pues seguir en la zona de comentarios no aporta a la comunidad

Comment: Ya hice las correcciones vanagloriosa persona.