# Python % o módulo

Tags: python

Siguiendo un manual de Python, no entiendo la explicación:

> *X dividido entre Y tiene como resto J" , 100 dividido entre 16 tiene como resto 4*

Entiendo lo que quiere decir resto etc, pero no logro entender como realiza tal operación:

```
100 - 25 * 3 % 4 = 97
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que te confunde? ¿Que significa o cómo se obtiene e resto de la división entera o por qué 100-25*3%4 da 97?  PAra esto último es crucial que entiendas el [orden de evaluación de los operadores](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve revisando tras la explicación y encontré la solución!

Comment: relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31549/81450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resto de una división es lo que queda, si una división no es exacta, por ejemplo, cuando uno trata de saber si una numero es par en programación, se usa

```
(num % 2) == 0
```

este código quiere decir, si el resto de 'num' dividido entre 2, es igual a 0, esto quiere decir que es par, por ejemplo

```
(10 % 2) == 0
```

esto devuelve verdadero, ya que el resto de 10 divido entre 2 es 0, el % hace referencia a este caso en el 0

Comment: Muchas gracias, estuve revisando tras la explicación y encontré la solución!

Comment: Puedes marcar mi respuesta como solución entonces