# Como alternar los colores de fila en un ListView en Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Tengo un ListView  personalizado al cual quiero alternar los colores de las filas una blanca una gris y así sucesivamente, he probado sacando el residuo de la división pero la lista comienza en cero así que me da dos seguidas del mismo color.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, viewGroup, false);

    double residuo = position/2;
    if (residuo==0){
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador aritmetico `%`, llamado operador módulo. El operador módulo da como resultado el resto de la división entera.

[¿Cómo funciona el operador %?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31543/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-operador)

Si deseas pintar la celda cuando el valor de la variable `position` es impar (1,3,5,7,9,11...), puedes usar:

```
  if(position % 2 == 1){
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
  }
```

si deseas pintar la celda cuando los valores son 0 o par (0,2,4,6,8,10...), puedes usar:

```
  if(position % 2 == 0){
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
  }
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la operación Mod(%)

Hago referencia a una respuesta en el foro de Stackoverflow en inglés.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109840/android-alternate-row-colors-in-listview?answertab=active#tab-top

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, viewGroup, false);

    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  
    }

    return v;
}
```

El residuo de las posiciones impares siempre será de 1 por lo tanto podrás alternar el color de fondo de cada vista, obteniendo su posición.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item, viewGroup, false);

    double residuo = (position+1)/2;
    if (residuo==0){
        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return v;
}
```

A mi parecer ya tenias la respuesta, lo que debes hacer es que position sume 1,  así iniciará en 1 y no en 0. Con eso se soluciona tu problema